# Is it required to define parameters in a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript

Is it required to define parameters in a javascript function?  My question is regarding my `comchoice` function down below, where I simply use the open and close parentheses without giving any parameters that can be changed.

I listed my full code for the script just for reference

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
var compchoice = function ()
{
    if (computerChoice <= 0.34) 
    {
        return computerChoice = "Rock";
    } 
    else if(0.35 <= computerChoice <= 0.67) 
    {
        return computerChoice = "Paper";
    } 
    if (0.68 <= computerChoice <= 1)
    {
        return computerChoice = "Scissors";
    }
};

compchoice();

var compare = function (choice1, choice2)
{
    if (choice1 === choice2)
    {
        return alert("The result is a tie!");
    }

    if (choice1 === "Rock")
    {
        if (choice2 === "Scissors")
        {
            return alert("Rock wins!");
        }
        else if (choice2 === "Paper")
        {
            return alert("Paper wins!");
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "Scissors")
    {
        if (choice2 === "Rock")
        {
            return alert("Rock wins!");
        }
        else if (choice2 === "Paper")
        {
            return alert("Schissors wins!");
        }
    }
};

compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

Comment: No, it's not required.

Comment: Of course not. Some functions just don't expect any arguments, so it would be silly to require every function to have parameters. Also, why are you asking? Is your code not working as expected? Learn more about defining functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function.

Comment: It depends on how you define your functions. If you need to use the passed arguments inside your function definition(as you are doing in your `compare` function), you might need to define those parameters but it's not something that javascript explicitly requires for every function.

Comment: `var foo = function {` is invalid code. `var foo = function() {` is not. Remember your parenthesises and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks Rapael Althaus!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is something like the following:

```
function RandomFunction(){
   alert( arguments[0] );
   console.log( arguments[1] );
}

RandomFunction( 'Hello World', 'Good bye' );
```

And find the arguments for the function in the  "arguments" variable within a function. Thus, no need to declare the argument, but declaring them is always a great way to go.

Also, instead of using traditional arguments, you can pass in an object to be used as an extensible list of objects:

```
function AnotherFunction( x ){
   alert( x.message );
}

AnotherFunction( {message: 'Hello Again, world'} );
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that although correct, the `arguments` parameter is not permitted in strict mode. It also is much more expensive than explicitly defining parameter so it should be avoided in blocking code.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not necessary to pass parameter, function can be with no parameter. In your case function is accessing the outer variables with closures.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Function Definition Syntax

> FunctionExpression :
>   function Identifier<sub>opt</sub> ( FormalParameterList<sub>opt</sub> ) { FunctionBody }<sub>[(ES5 §13)](http://es5.github.io/#x13)</sub>

In a function expression you can ommit the identifier as well as the parameters.

Hence your code is syntactically valid.

Comment: Could you please expand your answer? This looks more like a comment.

Comment: I sure will do so later when I'm back from mobile